# Swift 3 UITableViewDataSource selectors

Tags: ios, swift

After updating to Swift 3 I get error in following code:

```
extension MyViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    //...

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
                   heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return someValue
    }
}
```

> Objective-C method 'tableView:heightForRowAt:' provided by method
>   'tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)' does not match the requirement's
>   selector ('tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:')

It can be fixed with

```
@objc(tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:)
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return someValue
}
```

Could anyone explain motivation of signature changing in new version of Swift? There is no info in [migration guide](https://swift.org/migration-guide/) about it.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39416385/swift-3-objc-optional-protocol-method-not-called-in-subclass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the release of *Swift 3.0* the signatures of many methods in the library have been changed for the sake of readability (see [API Design Guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#naming)).

Compare for example the current signature of the method you quoted to its representation in the code completion suggestions list of *Xcode*:

```
// implementation:
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {...}

// code completion:
tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt: IndexPath)
```

In contrast the previous implementation used to show redundant information:

```
// implementation:
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {...}

// code completion:
tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath: NSIndexPath)
                                                ---------  -----------
```

Furthermore the implementation of a function or method now requires an underscore (`_`) to be set even for the first argument in order to allow omitting argument labels when calling the function/method (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38192263/6793476).

Obviously some selectors in the library haven't been updated yet so you need to provide proper ("the old") selector names (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39416386/6793476 and for more information about selectors: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24007718/6793476).

I hope that helps.