# Swift - Overriding functions with different default parameters

Tags: swift, swift3, default-parameters, overriding

Case: A base class (A) with a function (doSomething) that has a default parameter (param: T = foo), and a subclass (B) which overrides that function with a different default parameter (param: T = bar). **But is then called as A.**

Edit: Apologies for the original code, so actually what is happening is basically the following:

```
class Foo
{
    func doSomething(a: String = "123")
    {
        print(a)
    }
}

class Bar: Foo
{
    override func doSomething(a: String = "abc")
    {
        print("Using Bar method body... but not Bar's default a value!")
        print(a)
    }
}

(Bar() as Foo).doSomething()

// Prints:
// Using Bar method body... but not Bar's default a value!
// 123
```

Is it a bug or expected behaviour that it uses the functions body but doesn't use the functions default parameter?

Comment: Cannot reproduce, at least not with T replaced by String. The output is "bar" in Swift 3. Can you provide a self-contained example?

Comment: Looked into this further and it might loosely link to a different bug that we have seen [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39416385/swift-3-objc-optional-protocol-method-not-called-in-subclass) where it looks like the compiler / linker is only looking at the top level override of the function.

Comment: *That* one seems to be about Objective-C protocols, which I don't see in your example. Also `T` is undefined in your code. – Again: a self-contained example demonstrating the problem would be helpful.

Comment: @MartinR Apologies for the changes (new to posting of so) - we've had a look into this further and found the cause, and it makes sense, but why would it not take Bar's parameter over Foo's.

Comment: Are you sure that you observed a different behavior in Swift 2?

Comment: Thanks @MartinR, looks like it might have been - I'll correct the question

Answer (score 2):

It's being called as Foo (or A) *because you tell it to.* Because you're instantiating `Bar() as Foo`, it is doing ***exactly that.***

If you do:

```
Bar().doSomething()
```

Bar's method is what is called:

```
Using Bar method body...
abc
```

Interestingly, as you point out:

```
(Bar() as Foo).doSomething()
```

Yields:

```
Using Bar method body...
123
```

Because Bar is instantiated ***as*** Foo, (note emphasis) Bar gets Foo's default parameters, yet still executes Bar's function body.

Interesting observation!