# Core Bluetooth 'Instance method nearly matches optional requirement' warning

Tags: swift, xcode8, core-bluetooth

I am converting a project to Swift 3 and am having a similar issue to [Swift 3 ObjC Optional Protocol Method Not Called in Subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39416385/7542315) for the Core Bluetooth peripheral methods.

Instance method 'peripheral(*:didDiscoverServices:)' nearly matches optional requirement 'peripheral(*:didDiscoverServices:)' of protocol 'CBPeripheralDelegate'

However, when I add the @objc declaration as a workaround, I am getting this error:

Method cannot be marked @objc because the type of the parameter 2 cannot be represented in Objective-C

This is my declaration:

```
@objc(peripheral:didDiscoverServices:)
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
```

I am using Xcode 8.3.1

Any ideas?

Comment: The problem is that `Error` is an enum, and Objective-C can't handle optional enums.  I'm not sure how to work around it though.

Comment: Your code compiles for me, even without the `@objc`. Can you post a self-contained example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: @JohnMontgomery:  I don't think that is the problem. Swift bridges between `Error` and `NSError`. See https://developer.apple.com/reference/corebluetooth/cbperipheraldelegate/1518744-peripheral and switch between Swift and Objective-C.

Comment: It seems the issue was that Error was extended, which was causing the first error and preventing the objc bridging from working properly.